# Происхождение слова "вряд ли"

Tags: этимология

"Вряд ли" сейчас обозначает сомнение в чем-то. Но, если вдуматься в это слово: "в-ряд-ли". В какой ряд и причем тут это?

Answer (score 4):

По Фасмеру, именно от "ряд", как и навряд ли:

навряд навря́д (ли). Из вряд (въ + рѧдъ), усиленного с помощью на;

http://enc-dic.com/fasmer/Navrjad-8544.html

В настоящее время выражение "вряд ли" -   неизменяемая частица,но раньше, скорее всего, было неполное вопросительное предложение.
Может, слово произошло от определения логики и возможности этого события войти  в ряд нормы, положительного итога построения чего-либо. "Ли"-остаток от "или" - сомнение: "в ряд или не в ряд" или  "из ряда вон":

Если цепочку событий подвергали сомнениям, говорили "в ряд ли" получится. То есть было сомнение, ставить ли это в ряд с чем-то нормативным. Вряд ли исполнится, вряд ли произойдёт.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю "ряд" здесь не цепочка, а скорее шеренга, множество. Нечто правильно построенное. Сравните "Из ряда вон (выходящее)". Вот принадлежность к этому ряду некоторого утверждения и ставится под сомнение оборотом "в ряд ли (поставлено)", соответствует ли фактам (не логике).
Сюда же - рядить (делать правильным), урядник и проч.

*"Во избежание": Фасмеру я отнюдь не противоречу, а Людмиле возражаю только по части трактовки здешнего "ряда" как чего-то последовательного (хотя в другом случае и такое понимание ряда вполне возможно).*

Answer (score 2):

Мы, например, говорим: "вряд ли  возможно". Это может обозначать: мы сомневаемся, что В ОДНОМ РЯДУ С ИСТИНОЙ находится это утверждение.Или в одном ряду с ПРАВИЛЬНЫМ, ОБЩЕПРИНЯТЫМ. Частица ЛИ  имеет вопросительное значение с оттенком сомнения.

Answer (score -1):

Очень может быть, что слово "вряд ли" вместе с "на вряд ли" и "наряду" - так же, как слово "товарищ" от слова "товар" пришло из сленга торговцев... Попасть в ряд - это попасть в гущу торговли, ярмарки и т.п. "В ряд ли попадем?" - вопрошает торговец, опаздывая на торги или на ярмарку или на праздник...

Comment: Ничего не понял. А какое основание переносить ряд на гущу? К тому же есть куда более прозаическое объяснение для торгового происхождения. Про "торговые ряды" когда-нибудь слыхали? Ну и при чем тут далекая по смыслу гуща? Другое дело что при любой версии "в ряд ли попадаем" - это какая-то сумасшедшая грамматика. Торговцы русский язык знали - и ***вряд ли*** стали бы язык собственный так коверкать.

Answer (score -1):

Из вряд (въ + рѧдъ) - имеется в виду - "в рад (радость) ли" а не в "ряд" ли.
Что означает "будет ли это тебе в радость"; то есть сомнение "вряд ли" на самом деле может означать "в радость ли".
Например: Вряд ли я пойду с вами. (Будет ли мне в радость, если я пойду с вами).
Также, Древнерусское значение слова РЯД (аР+УД) – условие, соглашение, договор. Возможно и такое толкование: вряд ли - совпадает ли это с нашим соглашением? Отсюда значение сомнения.

Относительно слова "товарищ" - оно призошло не от слова товар, как считалось. Корень этого слова гораздо старше. Он исходит из иврита, от слова "тов" (хороший,добрый) и "ар" (большой, высокий). То есть товарищ - это человек (мужчина) хороший, большой (в смысле уважаемый) как для деловых, так и для дружеских отношений.

Comment: *не от слова товар, как считалось* — считалось до того, как Вы придумали свою версию?